# any way of convert a text into a url redeable?

Tags: python

Is there any way of converting text like this

```
can Python do this?
```

to

```
can-python-do-this
```

Like github rename title to url?

I tried with a lot replaces or whit `urllib.parse.quote`, but that return `%3F` for instead of `?`.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be a little overkill, but there is a module called slugify.

You can install it with

```
pip install slugify
```

And you would use it like this:

```
>>> from slugify import slugify
>>> slugify('Can python do THis?')
'can-python-do-this'
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with lower() and replace().

```
def makeLink(string):
   string.lower()
   string.replace(" ", "-")
   # remove question mark
   string.replace("?", "")
   return string
```